# finding value of $\cos^{-1}$ unsure why it changes to negative in answer

Tags: trigonometry

$\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)$ Another of the find the exact value of this questions. The answer it gives is:

$\cos^{-1}(\frac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}) = \theta \Leftrightarrow  \cos(a) = \frac{-\sqrt{3}}{2} \Rightarrow a = 150^{\circ}$

How do I know to use $-\sqrt{3}$ there? Because using positive gives a different answer. Or is this possibly a typo in the problem? (have had quite a few of those before in this class...)

Comment: Whoever changed the post, it's supposed to not be negative in that first $\cos^{-1}(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$. That's how it is on my paper, and that's what I'm asking, is that wrong? Is there just a typo on the paper?

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to format mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like your recent question about $\sin^{-1}$, this time the $\cos^{-1}(-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}) = \theta \iff \cos \theta = -\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, and $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$. Observe that $\cos \frac{5\pi}{6} = -\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. Thus $\theta = \dfrac{5\pi}{6}$ or $150^{\circ}$.

The first part which is $\cos^{-1} \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right) = \theta \iff 0\leq \theta \leq \pi$, and $\cos \theta = \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. But $\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right) = \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \Rightarrow \theta = \dfrac{\pi}{6}$ or $30^{\circ}$.

Comment: The second part that is negative is supposed to be the answer to the first part, which is positive. From what I've seen of these answers so far, I'm going to assume that yes, the question and the given answer on my handout are mismatched...

Comment: They are separate questions.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Must have been a typo on the handout then, missing - sign.

Answer (score 1):

Using [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values), $0\le\arccos(x)\le180^\circ$

If $\cos y=-\dfrac{\sqrt3}2=-\cos30^\circ=\cos(180^\circ-30^\circ)$ as $\cos(180^\circ-A)=-\cos A$

The general  value of $y$ is $n360^\circ\pm150^\circ$ where $n$ is any integer

The principal value will be $150^\circ$ it needs to satisfy $0\le y\le180^\circ$
can be found by setting $n=0$ and taking the '+' sign

Comment: Yea the original thing, the only thing it gives me to solve from is $\cos^{-1}(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$, where it's not negative. Just looking at this alone, how do I tell that I need to change it to a negative?

Comment: @windy401, https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100531161241AAiMXWx